# Find closest points between two tables in MySQL with Spatial extensions

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I have a two tables: one with trackings points and one with shops.
I want the trackings points that have 1 or more shops within a certain distance from that point.

What I have now:

```
SELECT 

a.*, 
b.*

FROM trackings_process a, shops b 
WHERE st_distance_sphere(a.coords_point, b.point) < a.coords_accuracy + 30

ORDER BY b.name, a.id
```

The distance is based on the accuracy of that tracking point.
My tracking points table contains 16.000+ records and my shops table has 8.000+ records. The query above takes 71s to run.

My questions: is this the best approach? Strategies to lower the execution time?